# LoadException while switching scenes and controllers

Tags: javafx, controller, fxml

I'm having trouble while switching scene and controller for my app using fxml views. At first I have login view and then I want to switch to lobby view and I don't how should I make it. I try to create object of new controller and load fxml file in its constructor but then I have LoadException and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Main App:

```
public class Client extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("LoginView.fxml"));
            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,300,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

LoginController:

```
private void loginSuccess() {
        //some login code
        if (result.get() == buttonContinue){
            proceedToLobby();
        }

    }


    private void proceedToLobby() {
        LobbyController lobbyController = new LobbyController(stage);

    }
```

LobbyController:

```
public LobbyController(Stage stage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("LobbyView.fxml"));
            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,400);
            this.stage = stage;
            this.stage.setScene(scene);
            this.stage.setResizable(false);
            this.stage.show();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

LoadException:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/student/eclipse-workspace/Pai-Roulette-Game/bin/roulette/client/LobbyView.fxml:9

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:932)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at roulette.client.LobbyController.<init>(LobbyController.java:33)
    at roulette.client.LoginController.proceedToLobby(LoginController.java:78)
    at roulette.client.LoginController.loginSuccess(LoginController.java:69)
    at roulette.client.LoginController.buttonClicked(LoginController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

LobbyView 9th line:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="roulette.client.LobbyController">
```

Comment: Your `LobbyView` instructs the `FXMLLoader` to create a new `LobbyController`, which loads `LobbyView.fxml`, which creates a new `LobbyController`, which loads `LobbyView.fxml`, which creates, etc. etc. Maybe you are trying to use [this pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components)?

Comment: @James_D Probably it stops when it first encounters the `fx:controller="roulette.client.LobbyController"` because of the missing 0-argument constructor... (Otherwise you'd get a stackoverflow instead of the exception posted.)

Comment: Ah yes, very true

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to load the view from the Controller's constructor. As James_D pointed out, the loader creates a controller upon loading, which in your case then creates a new loader and the loop continues.

May I suggest you simply load the scene in your `proceedToLobby()` method? Something like this:

```
  private void proceedToLobby() {

    try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("LobbyView.fxml"));
            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
            LobbyController fooController = (LobbyController ) fxmlLoader.getController();
            fooController.setStage(stage); // create this method if you need to use the stage
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,400);
            // these lines may not be necessary since the stage is already showing
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And then your controller constructor should be like this:

```
public LobbyController() {
}
```

If you need the controller to do stuff, then you can retrieve it from the loader as in the example above and create other public methods for the functionality.

**EDIT**: As stated in the comments, the loader expects an empty constructor which causes the error. Its not caused by constructing the view from the controller class.

Comment: It does not actually construct the `LobbyController` when loading the fxml. Otherwise the exception would be a `StackoverflowError`. It simply stops when it encounters a `fx:controller` attribute containing a class that does not provide a 0-argument constructor. Your approach will fail too without a modification of `LobbyController` that fixes this...

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I implied in my answer that the constructor should then be empty without stating it. I have added it.